# Filter by defining concrete entity as the operand, i.e. not using a primitive value

Tags: odata

In the [examples](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cos01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-cos01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793793) I've checked, the operand is always a primitive value, like:

```
http://host/service/Products?$filter=MainIngredient eq 'Milk'
```

what if the `MainIngredient` property is an entity, and I want to reference exactly this entity? Abstracting other cases, that would be something like

```
http://host/service/Products?$filter=MainIngredient eq Ingredient('770d5720-9ae8-11e3-a5e2-0800200c9a66)
```

...or isn't the filter not the correct instrument to use, at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that MainIngredient is the name of a navigation property that points to a single entity of type Ingredient, such as:

```
http://host/service/Products(1234)/MainIngredient
```

If this is the case, and assuming that the key of Ingredient is called "ID" then I think the correct form of URL for what you want to do is:

```
http://host/service/Products?$filter=MainIngredient/ID eq guid'770d5720-9ae8-11e3-a5e2-0800200c9a66'
```

That would return only products that are linked, via MainIngredient, to the Ingredient with the ID you gave in the question.

Comment: I feared that this is the way to do it, however I don't like handling/exposing the identity property (``guid``) so much, but well...